# Introducir dos inputs en una condicional de tipo número en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Cuando guardo dos inputs en una variable y los coloco en un condicional, creo que me lo está leyendo como un string y no como un número. Quiero que el resultado diga "vamos bien " y no "vamos mal ".
Este es el código

```js
  let valorUno =  parseInt(document.getElementById(`valorUno`));
  let valorDos  =  parseInt(document.getElementById(`valorDos`));


function Resultado() { 

  if (valorUno < valorDos) { 

     alert(`VAmos bien`); 
 } else { 
       alert(`vamos mal`); /* me sale `vamos mal` , deberia salir 
                               `vamos bien ` */
      
  }
      
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Centauro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span> <p>Precio de tela </p> <input id="valorUno" type="number">
          <p>Presupuesto </p> <input id="valorDos" type="number"> </span>
       <button onclick="Resultado()">Calcular</button>
       <div id="numFranelas"></div>
       <div id="numDocenas"></div>
       <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema es que al obtener el elemento mediante `getElementById` se te retorna todo el elemento en si y tu tienes que acceder a los atributos que necesitas, para tu caso sería el `value`. Por lo que deberías hacer `document.getElementById(`valorUno`).value` Ya que como lo tienes actualmente se hace el `ParseInt` a todo el elemento html lo que retorna `undefined` y de ahí que no se cumpla la condición.

Pero al hacer el cambio que te digo seguirá pasando lo mismo debido a que tu obtienes los valores al cargar la pagina pero cuando la pagina se carga aún no hay nada en los `input`. Lo recomendable sería obtener los valores de los `input` al momento de ejecutar la función.

```js
function Resultado() { 
     let valorUno =  parseInt(document.getElementById(`valorUno`).value);
     let valorDos  =  parseInt(document.getElementById(`valorDos`).value);

     if (valorUno < valorDos) { 
         alert(`VAmos bien`); 
     } else { 
         alert(`vamos mal`);  
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Centauro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span> <p>Precio de tela </p> <input id="valorUno" type="number">
          <p>Presupuesto </p> <input id="valorDos" type="number"> </span>
       <button onclick="Resultado()">Calcular</button>
       <div id="numFranelas"></div>
       <div id="numDocenas"></div>
       <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda